# Lisbox items save to text file with "," seprarate

Tags: vb.net

Hy!
How to save listbox items to textfile with "," seprate?

My code:

```
 Using sfd As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog

        With sfd
            .FileName = String.Empty
            .Filter = "Text|*.txt"
            .InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
        End With

        If sfd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim logint() As String = Login.Text.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            Dim passt() As String = Pass.Text.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            Dim contents As String = String.Empty
            For x As Integer = 0 To logint.Length - 1
                contents &= String.Format("{1},{2}{0}", Environment.NewLine, logint(x), passt(x))
            Next
            If contents.Length > 0 Then
                contents = contents.Remove(contents.Length - 1)
            End If
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(sfd.FileName, contents, False)
        End If
    End Using
```

It's working if I click a listbox item, but if I don't, then items save doesn't work.

Comment: Of course it doesn't save anything if you don't select an item. The `Text` property contains the displayed text of the selected item. What do you expect it to contain if there is no selected item? Are you trying to save all the items in the ListBox or only the selected ones?

Comment: Thank you. All listbox item. I ask for an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
If sfd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
    Dim contents As String = String.Empty '***
    Dim c As Integer = Login.Items.Count '***
    Dim y As Integer '***
    For y = 0 To c - 1 '***
        Dim logint() As String = Login.Items.Item(y).Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) '***
        Dim passt() As String = Pass.Items.Item(y).Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) '***
        For x As Integer = 0 To logint.Length - 1
            contents &= String.Format("{1},{2}{0}", Environment.NewLine, logint(x), passt(x))
        Next
        If contents.Length > 0 Then
            contents = contents.Remove(contents.Length - 1)
        End If
    Next '***
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(sfd.FileName, contents, False)
End If
```

Changes are marked with `'***`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bit of LINQ to do it in a single line:

```
IO.File.WriteAllLines("file path here",
                      Enumerable.Range(0, Login.Items.Count).
                                 Select(Function(n) String.Format("{0},{1}",
                                                                  Login.Items(n),
                                                                  Pass.Items(n))))
```